# How can you create a hive mind race?

Tags: stellaris

I wanted to make a tech-based hive mind species in Stellaris, but when I went through the whole list of options, I could not find anything that made your species into a hive-mind other than the naming convention. I remember watching playthroughs of the game were the AI were generated as hive-minds, but is there any way to make your own? Does it need any of the DLC's as I don't have any of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is in the Ethics circle - the icon in the exact middle. It is available only if have the Utopia DLC for the biological empire or "Synthetic Dawn" if you want a machine one:

[image]

Then on the right, under "Authority" you can select are you a machine or biological hive mind.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is "Biological Constructs" from a mod (first screen shot)? I've never noticed it before.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux  it looks like it - I've taken those photos from the Google